# PHP HTML Hyperlink Quotes Issue

Tags: php, onclick, onmousedown

I am trying to output a list of links based upon database query result. The query works fine but I need to get the information for the links to populated by the same results. In this example I need to create the following string to pass along to my `loadXMLDoc()` Function..

```
$ridesid
$catrating
```

This is the actual line of code that is giving me an issue:

```
echo "<a href='#' onmousedown='url1 ='attraction_page.php?rideid=$ridesid&catrating=$catrating onclick ='loadXMLDoc()'>$rides</a>";
```

I am pretty sure it is just an issue with the quotes but I have been searching and searching for a solution or an example of how to properly code this line but can't find anything. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Here is the complete PHP block:

```
<?php
    $sql3 = "SELECT `Record_ID`, `Name` FROM `rides` WHERE `Rating` = $catrating  ORDER BY `Name`";
    $result3=mysql_query($sql3)or die(mysql_error());
    //var_dump ($result3);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result3);
    //WHILE ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
        echo "<table>";
        // Ride Category Heading
        if ($catrating == 1)
            echo "<span class='headertext'>Kiddie Rides</span><br \>";
        if ($catrating == 2)
            echo "<span class='headertext'>Family Rides</span><br \>";
        if ($catrating == 3)
            echo "<span class='headertext'>Thrill Rides</span><br \>";
        // end heading
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){
            $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
            //var_dump($row3);
            $ridesid = $row3[0];
            $rides = $row3[1];


            //echo "<a href='attraction_page.php?rideID=". urlencode($ridesid) ."&catrating=". urlencode($catrating) ."'>$rides</a>";
            echo "<tr>";
            //echo "<a href='#' onmousedown='url1 ='attraction_page.php?rideID=$ridesid&catrating=$catrating' onclick='loadXMLDoc()'>$rides</a>";
            //echo "<a href='#' onmousedown='url1 ='attraction_page.php?rideID=30&catrating=1 onclick='loadXMLDoc()'>$rides</a>";
            //echo "<a href='attraction_page.php?rideID=". urlencode($ridesid) ."&catrating=". urlencode($catrating) ."'>$rides</a>";
            echo "<a href='#' onmousedown='url1 ='attraction_page.php?rideid=$ridesid&catrating=$catrating onclick ='loadXMLDoc()'>$rides</a>";
            echo "<br />";
            echo "</tr>";

        }

        echo '</table>';
//  }
    ?>
```

Comment: Is `loadXMLDoc()` a PHP function or Javascript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must escape your quotes.

```
echo "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onmousedown='url1 =\'attraction_page.php?rideid=$ridesid&catrating=$catrating\';' onclick ='loadXMLDoc()'>$rides</a>";
```

I would also replace the `#` in your `href` attribute with `javascript:void(0)`

Comment: You don't have to escape single quotes inside double quotes in PHP.

Comment: Actually, you couldn't be more wrong (in this case). This **is** PHP, but the PHP is generating Javascript. The javascript is what needs the escaped quotes.

Comment: I see your point, which is they are misusing single quotes.

Comment: I tried these solutions but this is what the browser is returning... <a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="url1 =\" attraction_page.php?rideid="30&amp;catrating=1'\;'" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Bumble Bees</a>

Comment: You did not copy my solution. `url=\'` NOT `url=\"`

Comment: This is the actual line of code that I have in the file.. echo "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onmousedown='url1 =\'attraction_page.php?rideid=$ridesid&catrating=$catrating'\;' onclick ='loadXMLDoc()'>$rides</a>"; this is the line of code when viewing the source code on the complete page... <a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="url1 =\" attraction_page.php?rideid="33&amp;catrating=1'\;'" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Kiddie Boats</a>

Comment: Neither PHP nor javascript will change a single quote to a double quote. I think you need to reinvestigate.

Comment: also, after the catrating variable, you have the `'` and `\` reversed, which was my mistake and corrected in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to leave quotes when you want to use a var, or use the {$var} syntax

```
            echo "<a href='#' onmousedown='url1 =\'attraction_page.php?rideid=".$ridesid."&catrating=".$catrating."\'' onclick ='loadXMLDoc()'>".$rides."</a>";
```

Comment: I also used Dutchie432 quote escapes in here, as I didn't notice that. Credit is given when credit is due. :)